# How do you log out of the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac, mac-appstore

When you are logged in with into the Mac App Store and it prompts for the password like this:

[image]

how do you log out without entering the password?

Answer (score 7):

Store Menu > Sign Out

[image: App Store Sign out image]

The downside is apps are tied to the ID, so you won't be able to update the same apps signed to another ID

Comment: You can sign out to prevent anyone who can access your computer from making purchases using your Apple ID.

Choose Store > Sign Out.